# Laravel 5.4 Events fired, but not broadcasted

Tags: laravel, redis, queue, beanstalkd, broadcasting

I have a problem with broadcasting comments on website:
- sometimes event listener handled event, but event not broadcasted.

**\App\Http\Controllers\CommentController in method "store":**

```
$comment = Comment::create($request->all());
broadcast(new NewCommentAdded($comment));
```

**\App\Events\NewCommentAdded**

```
namespace App\Events;

use App\Models\Comment;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PrivateChannel;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PresenceChannel;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Events\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\InteractsWithSockets;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Broadcasting\ShouldBroadcast;

class NewCommentAdded implements ShouldBroadcast
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

    public $comment;
    public $username;
    public $userimage;
    public $usergroup;
    /**
     * Create a new event instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(Comment $comment)
    {
        $this->comment = $comment;
        $this->username = $comment->user->name;
        $this->userimage = $comment->user->image;
        $this->usergroup = $comment->user->role_id;
    }

    /**
     * Get the channels the event should broadcast on.
     *
     * @return Channel|array
     */
    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        \Log::info('AddComment event broadcasted');
        return ['webinar_'.$this->comment->webinar_id];
    }

    public function broadcastAs()
    {
        return 'comment';
    }

}
```

**\App\Listeners\BroadcastNewComment**

```
namespace App\Listeners;

use App\Events\NewCommentAdded;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;

class BroadcastNewComment
{
//    use InteractsWithQueue;

    /**
     * Create the event listener.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {

    }

    /**
     * Handle the event.
     *
     * @param  NewCommentAdded  $event
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle(NewCommentAdded $event)
    {
        \Log::info('Added New Comment Event fired successfully');
    }
}
```

After all of this i getting logs:

```
[2017-12-06 16:02:03] production.INFO: Added New Comment Event fired successfully  
[2017-12-06 16:02:03] production.INFO: AddComment event broadcasted  
[2017-12-06 16:03:23] production.INFO: Added New Comment Event fired successfully  
[2017-12-06 16:03:24] production.INFO: AddComment event broadcasted  
[2017-12-06 16:03:58] production.INFO: Added New Comment Event fired successfully  
[2017-12-06 16:17:26] production.INFO: Added New Comment Event fired successfully  
[2017-12-06 16:17:27] production.INFO: AddComment event broadcasted
```

As you can see Event Listener handled event: **[2017-12-06 16:03:58] production.INFO: Added New Comment Event fired successfully** 
But Event not broadcasted.

My env:

```
BROADCAST_DRIVER=redis
QUEUE_DRIVER=beanstalkd
```

My supervisor config:

```
[program:ta-production-worker]
process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)02d
command=php /var/www/domains/data/www/somedomain.com/artisan queue:work --daemon --sleep=3 --tries=5
autostart=true
autorestart=true
user=root
numprocs=5
redirect_stderr=true
stdout_logfile=/var/www/domains/data/www/somedomain.com/storage/logs/worker.log
```

Comment: Have you configured your listeners to listen to that event? This can be done in `EventServiceProvider.php`

Comment: of course i did it  `'App\Events\NewCommentAdded' => [
            'App\Listeners\BroadcastNewComment',
        ],'App\Events\CommentDeleted' => [
            'App\Listeners\BroadcastDeleteComment',
        ],`

Comment: i see problem only sometimes, not on every event

Comment: I have the same problem, queue driver is beanstalkd, when the event is triggered, then the job appears in the beanstalkd, but it is not processed by the queue, the job is hold

Comment: Stop using Supervisor

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**The solutions of the problem :**

1. Stop using Supervisor or
2. Downgrade Supervisor or
3. Upgrade Supervisor.

I stopped using Supervisor and all works perfectly.